# Jamovi failed to show a plot

Tags: r, jamovi

Some laptop with a Hebrew user name failed to show plots in Descriptive in Jamovi 2.3.18

I opened Jamovi in debug mode and saw the following messages:

```
jamovi.server.server - listening across origin(s): 127.0.0.1:64652 127.0.0.1:64653 127.0.0.1:64654
jamovi.server.server - jamovi accessible from: 127.0.0.1:64652/?access_key=7b76b6f8ad9441a1889886c42ebce92c

ports: 64652, 64653, 64654, access_key: 7b76b6f8ad9441a1889886c42ebce92c

jamovi.server.session - creating instance: f25af653-5baf-47a5-9cc0-1018aa45d1c4

instance_started f25af653-5baf-47a5-9cc0-1018aa45d1c4

jamovi.server.session - creating instance: 4d3d54e2-6d7f-4dca-a18c-14ac6b98bf8c

instance_started 4d3d54e2-6d7f-4dca-a18c-14ac6b98bf8c

jamovi.server.session - destroying instance: f25af653-5baf-47a5-9cc0-1018aa45d1c4
instance_ended f25af653-5baf-47a5-9cc0-1018aa45d1c4

Uncaught exception GET /4d3d54e2-6d7f-4dca-a18c-14ac6b98bf8c/2/res/02%20descriptives/resources/14e8622d253285f2.png (127.0.0.1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:64654', method='GET', uri='/4d3d54e2-6d7f-4dca-a18c-14ac6b98bf8c/2/res/02%20descriptives/resources/14e8622d253285f2.png', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\jamovi 2.3.18.0\bin\Lib/site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1590, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "jamovi\Resources\jamovi\server\jamovi\server\server.py", line 120, in get
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\╫נ╫ץ╫¿╫ש╫ש╫ƒ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp0hr7g53g\\916e0323-151c-4d63-a10d-299c3a256f42\\4d3d54e2-6d7f-4dca-a18c-14ac6b98bf8c/02 descriptives/resources/14e8622d253285f2.png'

500 GET /4d3d54e2-6d7f-4dca-a18c-14ac6b98bf8c/2/res/02%20descriptives/resources/14e8622d253285f2.png (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
```

I suspect the failure to see the plot is caused by the Hebrew user name. Would appreciate your advice on how to handle this.

Comment: This should probably be posted here: https://github.com/jamovi/jamovi/issues, or comment on this one that appears to be the same problem: https://github.com/jamovi/jamovi/issues/1196

Comment: Tanks Ben , I'll do so

Answer (score 0):

The gist of your problem seems to be directly related to this error message:

```
 No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\╫נ╫ץ╫¿╫ש╫ש╫ƒ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp0hr7g53g\\916e0323-151c-4d63-a10d-299c3a256f42\\4d3d54e2-6d7f-4dca-a18c-14ac6b98bf8c/02 descriptives/resources/14e8622d253285f2.png'
```

There are likely two reasons for this problem:

- Jamovi cannot find this folder, because it has been modified in some way since the file was originally created.
- It could be that because the file is named in Hebrew, it may not parse
  the string correctly when loading through Jamovi. If this is the
  case, you could consider simply renaming the directory and seeing if
  that alleviates the issue. Johnathon Love in fact [mentions this](https://github.com/jamovi/jamovi/issues/781)
  as a potential issue in Jamovi/R at times.